# Log JSON to DataDog log message field

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, datadog

**I'd like to be able to send logs to datadog and have the message be a JSON object rather than a string.**

The metadata fields aren't searchable unless a facet is created, which I would like to avoid doing.

I'm currently using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) + [winston-datadog-logs-transporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelf/winston-datadog-logs-transport) to send the logs.

If I do: `logger.info(JSON.stringify(message))`, datadog records the message as blank and adds the stringified message as metadata.

If I do: `logger.info('foo' + JSON.stringify(message)`, then the message is interpreted as a string and I can search on it.

If I do: `logger.info('foo', message)`, the body is set to `foo` and `message` is interpreted as metadata, which I cannot search for without creating a facet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems you have a solution; what are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston')
const { combine, timestamp, json } = format

function dataDogLogger(options) 
{
    const logger = createLogger({
        exitOnError: false,
        format: combine(
            // add a timestamp to all logs
            timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
            json()
        ),
        transports: [ ...whatever you need here... ]
    })

    return logger
}

module.exports = dataDogLogger
```